# How to pass path variable to JPA repository from controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, repository

How to pass a path variable to `JPA` repository from controller.

I have a controller here and from the front End I am getting a variable.

Here is my controller :

```
@GetMapping("/getTransictionsAndInstruments/{id}")
    public List<TransictionProjection> getTransitionInstrument(@PathVariable Long id){
        return transictionrepository.getTransictionsAndInstruments();
    }
```

Based on this id I want some alteration in my result. I have already a query and  want to use this id in the repository. So how can I pass that in the repository.

```
@Repository
public interface TransictionRepository extends JpaRepository<Transictions, Long>{
    
    @Query(value = "SELECT transiction.user_id, transiction.quantity, transiction.instrument_name, transiction.Price, instrument.LTP, instrument.jo_caps FROM instrument INNER JOIN transiction ON instrument.instrument = transiction.instrument_name where transiction.User= id", nativeQuery = true)
    
    
    List<TransictionProjection> getTransictionsAndInstruments();
}
```

I want to include this line in my query         `where transiction.User= id`

Any help how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be achieved by following:
Adding `:id` in your native query and passing `id` in function.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT transiction.user_id, transiction.quantity, transiction.instrument_name, 
transiction.Price, instrument.LTP, instrument.jo_caps FROM instrument INNER JOIN transiction ON instrument.instrument = transiction.instrument_name 
where transiction.User= :id", nativeQuery = true)
List<TransictionProjection> getTransictionsAndInstruments(Long id);
```

Comment: worked thanks. Also i need to update controller as well/

Comment: Yeah. 
Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("Your query WHERE id = :userId")

List<Result> Method(@Param("userId") Long userId);
```